# Can I install specific dependencies based on profiles in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have an application which is supposed to run on different environments. Each of these environments uses different dependencies which are not compatible with one another. For eg. hibernate version

Can I make use of profiles in pom.xml to somehow decide at build time which dependencies get installed?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: yes, but you will only get one artifact for each execution of the build. And it won't be differenciated from other artifacts (no qualifier). You'd rather use submodules, each defining its own dependencies, and all are going to be built at the same time. With only a single ``mvn clean install/deploy`` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed were two profiles which are activated based on the Jdk versions.
For one of my environment I was having jdk1.7 and for another jdk1.8.

Here is what my pom looks like now.

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
   <id>Env1</id>
   <activation>
     <jdk>1.7</jdk>
   </activation>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>Any dependency you want</dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </profile>
 <profile>
   <id>Env2</id>
   <activation>
     <jdk>1.8</jdk>
   </activation>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>Any dependency you want</dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </profile>
</profiles>
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: So here you have to build your artifact twice, once for each profile, and that will deploy the very same artifact name twice, first being overwritten by the second?

Comment: @Spi.. Yes. There will be two different wars. I have two separate jenkins job as of now for the two environments.